# Regular expression: is there a way to set maximum size of pattern?

Tags: regex

For example, if I have the string:
`0123456789`

I would write expresion like this:
`0.*9 WHERE PATTERN MAX SIZE is 3. in this case, pattern should fail.`

Comment: So you're looking for the digit zero, any character, and the digit 9, and the pattern must only match a string of 3 characters?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us with a list of strings that must match, and strings that must not match.

Answer (score 8):

The specific solution to your example is:

```
/^0.?9$/
```

The general solution to your abstract question is:

```
/^(?=.{0,3}$)0.*9$/
```

In the above `(?=.{0,3}$)` is a lookahead that the rest of the string has length between 0 and 3.

Comment: Neat... never thought about using a look-ahead to limit the string length, although it would probably be easier to do that outside the regex.

Answer (score 6):

`x{min,max}` will match x between min and max times
`x{min,}` will match x at least min times
`x{,max}` will match x at most max times
`x{n}` will match x exactly n times

*All ranges are inclusive.*

Shortcuts: `{0,1}` => `?`, `{0,}` => `*`, `{1,}` => `+`.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but it should help you build your regex.

Example: `^0\d{,3}9$` will match strings with at most 5 digits starting with 0 and ending with 9. Matches: `0339`, `06319`, `09`. Does not match: `033429`, `1449`.

Comment: Seems like he needs `\d{0,3}`

Comment: @atomizer I think he needs something like `^0\d?9$`, but doesn't know how to ask it :).

Comment: @stefano This guy does it better: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: i try to explain better :)
i should create a little regualar expression editor. there will be a field where user set "maximum pattern size"
so, if i writes 0.* 
with "maximum pattern size" = 3 regular expression should consider just 012 and not 0123456789
i hope i am clear!

Comment: @stefano m: What do you mean by "should consider"? Do you mean "should accept"? Can you give an example showing the specific results you want for a variety of inputs?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to programmatically alter the regex.

**Please specify the language you are using (JS, Python, PHP, etc.).**

Here's how you could do it using JavaScript:

```
sYourPattern    = '0.*9';
iPatternMaxSize = 3;

zRegex = new RegExp ('^(?=.{0,' + iPatternMaxSize + '}$)' + sYourPattern + '$');
alert (zRegex.test ('09') );
```

This gives:

```
    '9'     --> No match
    '09'    --> Match
    '009'   --> Match
    '0009'  --> No match
    '19'    --> No match
```